# Figure and table captions in capital letters

Tags: captions

My `subfigure` command produces the caption for subfigure as `(A)` and also caption for figure as `FIGURE`. I do not know which package is doing this. Therefore I am providing all my code.

I know this is a bit lengthy, so approach this problem only in your free time.

Thanks

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{subcaption} %incompatible with subfig
\usepackage[]{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{cancel} 
\singlespacing
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}
    \centering
    \tikz{ %
        \node[latent]                       (phi)   {$\boldsymbol{\phi}$};
        \node[latent,   above = of phi]     (y)     {$\mathbf{y}$};
        \node[obs,      above = of y]        (Obs_y) {$ \tilde {\bf{y}}$};
        \node[latent,   left = of Obs_y]   (sigma) {$\sigma_y$};
        \edge {phi} {y};
        \edge {y, sigma} {Obs_y};
}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Probabilistic graph}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Where Thesis.cls is defined as:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Thesis LaTeX Template - THESIS CLASS FILE
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.latextemplates.com
%
% This class file defines the structure and design of the template. 
%
% There is one part of this file that needs to be filled out - the variables
% dictating the document particulars such as the author name, university
% name, etc. You will find these in the commented "DOCUMENT VARIABLES"
% section below.
%
% The other two easily-editable sections are the margin sizes and abstract.
% These have both been commented for easy editing. Advanced LaTeX
% users will have no trouble editing the rest of the document to their liking.
%
% Original header:
%% This is file `Thesis.cls', based on 'ECSthesis.cls', by Steve R. Gunn
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% Created by Steve R. Gunn, modified by Sunil Patel: www.sunilpatel.co.uk
%% Further modified by www.latextemplates.com
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Thesis}
              [2007/22/02 v1.0
   LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
\def\@checkoptions#1#2{
  \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
  \@tempswafalse
  \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
    \ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
  \let\@this\@empty
  \if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
}
\@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\baseclass}
\newcommand\bhrule{\typeout{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}

\newcommand\Declaration[1]{
\btypeout{Certificate}
\addtotoc{Certificate}
\thispagestyle{plain}
%\null\vfil
%\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\huge\bf Certificate\par}\end{center}
%\vskip 60\p@
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null
%\cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand\Preface[1]{
\btypeout{Preface}
\addtotoc{Preface}
\thispagestyle{plain}
%\null\vfil
%\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\huge\bf Preface \par}\end{center}
%\vskip 60\p@
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null
%\cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand\btypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space \number\year}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
\usepackage{vmargin}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Allows the use of international characters (e.g. Umlauts)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setmarginsrb  { 3.5cm}  % left margin
                        { 2.5cm}  % top margin
                        { 2.5cm}  % right margin
                        { 2.5cm}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\topskip}{1\topskip \@plus 5\p@}
\doublehyphendemerits=10000       % No consecutive line hyphens.
\brokenpenalty=10000              % No broken words across columns/pages.
\widowpenalty=9999                % Almost no widows at bottom of page.
\clubpenalty=9999                 % Almost no orphans at top of page.
\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999    % Almost never break footnotes.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{Equation~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\cref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\aref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.75}
\setcounter{topnumber}{9}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{9}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{20}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstpatch}
\lstset{captionpos=b,
        frame=tb,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keepspaces=true}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab} {
        language=Matlab,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.55,0.13}\em,
        stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.7,0,0} }
\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
   bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,
   colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red},
   pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
   \let\\\space
}

% The default title page, this is not used in this www.latextemplates.com version            
\renewcommand\maketitle{
  \btypeout{Title Page}
  \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
  \hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
  \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \null\vfil
    \vskip 60\p@
    \begin{center}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      {\large\textbf{\UNIVNAME}\par}
      \vfill
      {\huge \bf \@title \par}
      \vfill
      {\LARGE by \par}
      \smallskip
      {\LARGE \authornames \par}
      \vfill
      {\large A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment for the \par}
      {\large degree of \degreename \par}
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\large in the \par}
      {\large \facname \par}
      {\large \deptname \par} 
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\Large \@date \par}
      \bigskip
    \end{center}
    \par
    \@thanks
    \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
  \cleardoublepage
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT PAGE DESIGN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{abstract}
{
  \btypeout{Abstract Page}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  %\null\vfil
  \begin{flushleft}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    %{\normalsize \UNIVNAME \par} % University name in capitals
    %\bigskip
    {\centering{\huge{\textit{Abstract}}} \par}
    \bigskip
    \HRule \\[0.2cm] % Horizontal line
        Name of the student:     \textbf{\authornames}  \hfill Roll No: \textbf{\rollno} \\
        Degree for which submitted:  \textbf{\degreename} \hfill Department:  \textbf{Civil Engineering} \\
        Thesis title: \textbf{\@title}\\
        Thesis supervisor:  \textbf{\supname}\\
        Month and year of thesis submission: \textbf{{\large \today}\\[0.2cm] }
        \HRule \\[0.2cm] % Horizontal line  

  \end{flushleft}
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
  \cleardoublepage
}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\newcounter{dummy}
\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\btypeout{Table of Contents}
\addtotoc{Contents}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
   \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{
\btypeout{List of Figures}
\addtotoc{List of Figures}
\begin{spacing}{1.15}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{9pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
    \@starttoc{lof}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoftables{
\btypeout{List of Tables}
\addtotoc{List of Tables}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listtablename
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
    \@starttoc{lot}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\newcommand\listsymbolname{Abbreviations}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofsymbols[2]{
\btypeout{\listsymbolname}
\addtotoc{\listsymbolname}
    \chapter*{\listsymbolname
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}{\MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listconstants{Physical Constants}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofconstants[2]{
\btypeout{\listconstants}
\addtotoc{\listconstants}
    \chapter*{\listconstants
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listconstants}{\MakeUppercase\listconstants}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listnomenclature{Symbols}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofnomenclature[2]{
\btypeout{\listnomenclature}
\addtotoc{\listnomenclature}
    \chapter*{\listnomenclature
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}{\MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\acknowledgements[1]{
\btypeout{Acknowledgements}
\addtotoc{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{center}{\huge{\textit{Acknowledgements}} \par}\end{center}
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null

}
\newcommand\dedicatory[1]{
\btypeout{Dedicatory}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\Large \sl #1}\end{center}
\vfil\null
\cleardoublepage
}
\renewcommand\backmatter{
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \addtotoc{\bibname}
  \btypeout{\bibname}
  \@mainmatterfalse}
\endinput
```

Comment: Since the class file loads the `caption` package, why do you load it again in the preamble? And, have you tried to make use of the machinery of the `caption` package to achieve your formatting goal?

Comment: well I have downloaded the class file and did not bothered what all packages were there. I do not know how to use machinery.

Comment: The class file contains the instruction `\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}`. Here, "sc" stands for "small-caps fonts". If you don't like this setting, all you need to do is edit the class file and remove the "sc" option.

Comment: Templates like this are only a good idea as long as everything works to your satisfaction, as soon as you want to change something you end up in a huge mess of spaghetti code: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/ourFamousThesisTemplate.md, https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @Mico, that has worked. Kindly answer this question, I will accept it.

Comment: @moewe This was the original that later became Mastersdoctoralthesis. But I guess you already know that.

Comment: @Johannes_B Ah, I see. Thanks. I didn't really know that, but then again the evolution of this template and its friends is not high up my list of interests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document class you employ features the following instruction:

```
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
```

The `sc` option directs the contents of captions to be typeset in small-caps.  Since you don't want small-caps, just edit the class file and remove the `sc` option.

While you're at it, you may want to ask yourself if the other two package options -- `centerlast` and `small` -- are desirable. If not, by all means delete them as well. (To learn more about the `caption` package, type `texdoc caption` at a command prompt. This should bring up the package's user guide in pdf format.) And, after you're done adjusting the options of the `caption` package, you should go through the rest of the class file and ask yourself if loading various packages helps you achieve *your* typesetting needs. If not, delete (or at least comment out) the corresponding `\usepackage` and `\RequirePackage` directives. After you're done with combing through the class file, do also check how many of the nineteen [19!] `\usepackage` statements contained in your preamble are really needed.